# How do I know if an input sting is a method name of a specific class?

Tags: php, oop

Inside an object, I get a string and I have to know if there is a method with the same name in the current object I am in.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`method_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php). Here's an example:

```
$methodname = 'asdf';
if(method_exists($this, $methodname)) {
  // call_user_func(array($this, $methodname)); See comments
  $this->{$methodname}();
}
```

Comment: why `call_user_func` and not `$this->{$methodname}()`?

Comment: Because I didn't think of your suggestion. That would definitely also work and it looks like it might perform better: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php#64415

Answer (score 1):

```
if (method_exists ($this, $methodName)) {
    ... exists
}
```